# How to do a nested lambda in razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have the following:

`@Html.DisplayFor(mr => mr.Tooltip);`

`mr` in the lambda expression is type of `List<UIExternalService>`.

I want to access an individual `UIExternalService`.

So I tried adding a loop around it like:

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(mr => mr.Tooltip)
}
```

However `mr` is still a `List<UIExternalService>`, how can I give `DisplayFor()` the current element from the loop? Something like: `DisplayFor(m => m.Tooltip)` where `m` is the current element of foreach loop.

Comment: then use an indexer. ie `@Html.DisplayFor(mr => mr[index_here].Tooltip)`

Comment: Could you please share your view model?  The view's model is List<UIExternalService>?

Answer (score 2):

Use an indexer.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(mr => mr[index_here].Tooltip)
```

If you want to display for all records in the collection then use a `for` loop and again access the Model indexer

```
@for (var index = 0; index < Model.Count; index ++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(mr => mr[index].Tooltip)
}
```

Comment: What about: `@Html.DisplayFor(mr => m.Tooltip)` this would also work correct?